# Upload video to different channel using Youtube API, Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api

I use Yt gem to work with Youtube API and upload video using Yt::Account class.

The problem is that I need to allow user to choose channel to upload to – for example, one user has a second channel related to Google Plus page and this user should be able to upload video to that Youtube channel, not user's default one.

It seems like Yt misses the ability to specify channel (or I missed something).

I found also examples from Google https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby but all it says is "upload a video to the channel associated with the request" – and nothing about how to associate different channel.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you share the code of uploading process?

Comment: And why couldn't you generate request per channel?

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/uploading-videos-youtube-rails/) tutorial helpful. I'd also recommend looking up the Youtube API OAuth 2.0 [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).